# How to make the rate be in any number. For example: rate = n

Tags: c

How can I fix this code? And also, my problem here is how to make the rate be in any number. For example: `rate = n`

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int hours, rate, pay;

    hours = 40;
    rate = n;

    printf("Type forty: ");
    scanf("%d", &hours);

    printf("Your desired rate: ");
    scanf("%d", &rate);

    pay = 40 * rate;

    pay = hours*rate+(hours-40)*rate*1.5;
    printf("The result is %d");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please turn up compiler warnings and read them carefully. You should get some warning about missing argument for `%d` format specifier in last call to `printf`. For GCC you can turn up warning level using `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What input do you provide and what output do you get? What did you expect instaed?

Comment: What's the point of `rate = n`? You're going to ask the user for the rate.

Comment: *"my problem here is how to make the rate be in any number. For example: rate = n"* Do you mind elaborate on that? Also, what value do you want `pay` to have? Please explain in plain english what this program is supposed to do.

Comment: You ask the user for the `rate`. What is missing compared with your required "be in any number"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you always calculate the overtime, even when the number of hours is less than 40; and in doing so, you calculate too much for the overtime.

So, instead of this:

```
pay = 40 * rate;

pay = hours*rate+(hours-40)*rate*1.5;
```

where the first line has no effect anyway, as it is overwritten by the second line, write (for example)

```
if (hours <= 40) {
    pay = hours * rate;
}
else {
    pay = 40*rate+(hours-40)*rate*1.5;
}
```

Please note that the literal `40` apperaring three times in the code is something that is ugly and should be replaced by a variable of symbolic constant.

Comment: You could also add about missing argument in `printf("The result is %d");`

Comment: Thanks, @WedaPash, I missed that bug.

Answer (score 1):

A more stable version of this code would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned int rate, hours;
    const unsigned int maxHours = 40;
    unsigned long pay = 0;

    printf("Type forty (or more): ");
    scanf("%i", &hours);
    printf("Your desired rate: ");
    scanf("%i", &rate);
    if(hours > maxHours) {
        pay = (hours*rate)+(hours-maxHours)*rate*1.5;   
    }
    else {
        pay = hours*rate;   
    }
    
    printf("The result is %lu", pay);
    return 0;
}
```

This code addresses the following issues:

1. It only calculates the additional pay if the hours exceed 40. The issue correctly identified by [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69986501/4228131), credit to him!
2. It takes care of the bug with missing argument in the last `printf()` where the pay value is intended to be printed
3. [optional] Hours and rate is logically (most likely to be) always positive values, so uses `unsigned int` instead of `int`
4. [optional] Data type for `pay` is changed to `unsigned long` so that it covers the scenario if the values of `rate`  and `hours` are high enough to overflow the range of `unsigned int`

Comment: Point 3 is debatable, but if you go that way, please note that `%d` is the wrong format specifier.

Comment: @Bob__: Agreed.

Comment: If we worry about 4., using `unsigned int` might make it harder to detect that (unlikely) problem.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller: Thats why I have used `unsigned long` for the `pay` variable.

Comment: @WedaPashi Oh, I see.  Makes sense.